# Media Only Query Not Functioning as Intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write some jQuery that responds at the same time as my CSS media only queries.

I have objects that slide onto the web page at a specific scroll point. But in order to keep the objects responsive, I need to change the scroll point using media queries.

Heres the code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

            //media query scroll point @ min 768, max 995

            if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 995 && document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 768) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                    if (jQuery('.rightSlideB').hasClass('visible') == false) {
                        jQuery('.rightSlideB').stop().animate({
                            right: '0px'
                        }, function () {
                            jQuery('.rightSlideB').addClass('visible')
                        });
                    }
                }
            } //end media query

            //default scroll point

            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
                if (jQuery('.rightSlideB').hasClass('visible') == false) {
                    jQuery('.rightSlideB').stop().animate({
                        right: '0px'
                    }, function () {
                        jQuery('.rightSlideB').addClass('visible')
                    });
                }
            } //end default scroll point
        }); //end function
```

The media only screen that my content responds to is this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 995px) {}
```

Not only is the jQuery not creating the desired effect, but my code is incredibly inefficient and the main block of:

```
if (jQuery('.rightSlideB').hasClass('visible') == false) {
                        jQuery('.rightSlideB').stop().animate({
                            right: '0px'
                        }, function () {
                            jQuery('.rightSlideB').addClass('visible')
                        });
                    }
```

is being repeated. How can I trim that section down because it is being recycled in every media query any way.

EDIT: Should I be placing that repeating block into a function and then call it every time?

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Perhaps you should put the default block to the top (if it fits most situations) to give it a priority. 2. Add an `if` condition to the default block too that is the opposite of what you do in the media query. 3. Join them with an `if else` conditional

Comment: I will give that a shot! Thanks

Comment: Added as an answer too below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should put the default block to the top (if it fits most situations) to give it a priority. And add an if condition to the default block too that is the opposite of what you do in the media query. Lastly Join them with an if else conditional:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
 if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 995) {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
   if (jQuery('.rightSlideB').hasClass('visible') === false) {
    jQuery('.rightSlideB').stop().animate({
     right: '0px'
    }, function () {
     jQuery('.rightSlideB').addClass('visible');
    });
   }
  }
 } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 995 && document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 768) {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
   if (jQuery('.rightSlideB').hasClass('visible') === false) {
    jQuery('.rightSlideB').stop().animate({
     right: '0px'
    }, function () {
     jQuery('.rightSlideB').addClass('visible');
    });
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: It works up until 200% zoom on google chrome. If I zoom into 250% (still within that media only CSS query), The slide-in does not occur. Maybe my breakpoints are wrong? Will you access my site in order to see the error? If so, I will comment the link and instructions to replicate the issue. Thank you

Comment: Sure I'll have a look.

Comment: Keep in mind that jQuery's `scrollTop()` calculates the page scroll's position relative to html content. When you zoom in html content's size changes and that calculation ends-up with different results.

Comment: http://provix.net/index.asp The site is only responsive up to the 250% mark. I have only applied your code to the second block (Over 28 Years of Service). Refresh your page in order to re-spawn the slide in effect. Notice that it breaks at 250%, but functions like I need it to at 100% and 200%. Thanks @Barış Ürüm

Comment: Noticing now that even at 110% the slide in does not happen where I want it to, I need it to happen in the middle of the screen. Maybe I need to go about this differently then. :/

Comment: Maybe you should use native javascript's `offsetTop` property at this point. `offsetTop` gives an element's position relative to parent element's top. If you get the `offsetTop` of an element directly child of `<body>` that would give you a better result with zoom involved.

Comment: Hmm I will have read up on the documentation for offset(). Thanks for all the help. I will mark your answer as best once this question stews for a bit.

Comment: Yes that would work if you pick an element out of the html flow (position fixed) and compare it with the top element's (`<body>`) offsetTop.

Answer (score 1):

So here is my final solution.

First I turned that repeating block of code into a function:

```
$.fn.fromRight = function () {
            if (jQuery('.rightSlideB').hasClass('visible') === false) {
                jQuery('.rightSlideB').stop().animate({
                    right: '0px'
                }, function () {
                    jQuery('.rightSlideB').addClass('visible');
                });
            }
        };
```

Next, I set up new media queries (according to the most popular mobile devices) and then called the function each time the scroll height needed to be checked:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1440) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1440 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1366) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 275) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1366 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1280) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 325) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 800) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 800 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 475) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 768 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 600) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 600 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 567) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 567 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 414) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 414 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 384) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 384 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 375) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 375 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 360) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 360 && document.documentElement.clientWidth > 320) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            } else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 320) {
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 425) {
                    $.fn.fromRight();
                }
            }

        });
```

Now I just need to scrap my old CSS media queries and follow these new ones. There you have it, responsive web design is so much fun isn't it? ;)